# Reading CSV with special character using python

Tags: python, pandas, csvfix

I want to read the below CSV file into read_csv, due to the special characters in the CSV file , cant read the file properly, missing special characters in the column names in the data frame , and data is going here and there, but excel data is showing properly.
can you help to fix this issue, want to skip 5 rows and read the remaining data as it is and rename the column name

CSV file:-
$$PROGRAM$$ transistor.csv
$$DEVICE$$ 1
$$LOT$$ lot
$$DATE$$ 7/28/2021

$$FORMAT$$ ,SERIAL,COND=Temp,COND=vdd
1,BA1,25,1.2,7/12/201
1,BA2,25,1.2
1,BA2,25,1.2
1,BA3,25,1.2

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x=pd.read_csv(r"\trial.csv",index_col=None, header=0, skiprows=5, error_bad_lines=False,low_memory=False,encoding='utf8')
```

OUTPUT:-X

SERIAL COND=Temp   COND=vdd-
1   BA1 25  1.2 7/12/201-
1   BA2 25  1.2 NaN-
1   BA2 25  1.2 NaN-
1   BA3 25  1.2 NaN-

Expected output:
[image]

what iam getting:-
[image]

Comment: What would you expect? It seems fine to me, you have 4 columns, the last one has 4 missing values. Using `index_col=0` is not going to prevent the first value to be used as index, but you can do `x=x.reset_index()`. Please provide the expected output for more help

Comment: @mozway Thank you for response , please refer to question for expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your first row of data actually contains 5 values while your header only has 4 column names (the name for the date column is missing).

You can try to skip the header and provide column labels:

```
pd.read_csv(r"\trial.csv",
    skiprows=6,
    names=['FORMAT', 'SERIAL', 'COND=TEMP', 'COND=vdd', 'date'],
    error_bad_lines=False,
    low_memory=False,
    encoding='utf8')
```